# Draw a bar chart inJupyter

Tags: python

I want to draw a bar chart with 3 variables in `jupyter` and I can't.
For example I want to draw a bar chart to show every buyer and how much of everything they buy.

[image]

Comment: Please provide minimal reproducible sample.

Comment: Check this out - https://github.com/bgswaroop/python-matplotlib/blob/master/Matplotlib_Part2_BarCharts.ipynb